# I want to access the text of an MDTextField directly from the custom class with MyTextField.text but I'm getting <AliasProperty name=text>

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

python

```
Class MyTextField(MyTextField):
    pass

class CustomIconItem(OneLineAvatarIconListItem):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.venus = []

    def create_playlist(self, txt):

        app = MDApp.get_running_app()

        if MyTextField.text == "":
            pass
        else:
            
        self.venus.append(MyTextField.text)


        data = [{"text": str(self.venus[i]), "size_hint_x": 1}
                for i in range(len(self.venus))]

        app.root.ids.rp.data = data
```

Comment: You don't provide enough information for a complete answer, but you cannot access the `text` property of an instance of `MyTextField` through the class object. You must access the `text` property of an instance of `MyTextField` through the instance of `MyTextField`.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I created a variable to store the MDTextField in a function and it worked

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) addressing your main problem.

Comment: I've fixed the problem, there's no need worrying. Thanks very much for your concern